# Testing White label iOS and Android mobile apps

Tags: testing, android, ios, mobile, test-automation

We are in the process of developing white label apps for iOS and Android app. I was thinking about the test strategy for handling white label apps with minimum resources. My company is targeting for at least 50 customers for the first year.

1. Is there a way to handle white-label app with limited resources(testers)?
2. For every white labeled app, Do we need to repeat the same test cases/scripts? Is there any strategy to minimize the effort?
3. How can we manage Test automation? Is it required to run the same automation scripts on 50apps?
4. Is there any better approach or test strategy while doing testing for white label apps?

About White Label Apps:

1. Customer who uses our white label app will get their app re-branded with their own theme, logo, and little customization.
2. We will manage our customer apps hosting and take care all of app maintenance.
3. Keep pushing updates such as bug fixes, performance tuning, and new features.

Please let me know if further explanation is required, I would be happy to do so.

Answer (score 3):

As you will have many apps that only differ in their look and feel, but with 99+% the same functionality, it is really important that you have a really good separation of the functionality of the app and it's look-and-feel.
If you do that properly, then you can test all the functionality either without a UI or with a basic, brand-neutral UI.

With the functionality separated out, each customized app only needs to be tested on what is specific for that app, i.e. the branding/styling and the custom functionality that you created for that customer.
Plus a bit of happy-path end-to-end testing to verify that the branding didn't accidentally break the functionality.

As for automation, the tests of the brand-neutral version can all be automated so you can execute them really often. 
The tests on the branded versions are mostly end-to-end tests where you also look at the look-and-feel of the app. Those tests can't really be automated, but you also don't need to do them that often.